# Keypad not showing on ios8

Tags: ios8, keyboard, keypad

It was performed as follows.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[view addSubView:nameTextField];
[nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];`
```

But the keypad does not appear.

After you press the Home key, and if you come back to the application, the keypad appears.

I do not know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

check with Below code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillDisappear:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
        // Do something here
    }

    func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
        // Do something here
    }
```

and don't forget to remove observer in viewwillappear like below :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, check the results, there was no problem. There is not problem after update to IOS 9. It seems have problem in ios 8.